# Trading strategy for a misspecified density

Tags: options, quant-trading-strategies, risk-neutral-measure, forecasting, density

I am trying to implement a strategy that exploits potential misspecifications in density predictions (e.g.: long states with too-low probability; short states with too-high probability).

In particular, I am looking for an option-based strategy that exploits:

1. The **location** of the forecast density (i.e.:  misspecified mean): Which strategy could be used to benefit from a density prediction that is displaced to the left/right?
2. The **scale** of the forecast density (i.e.: missspecified volatility): Which strategy could be used to benefit from a density prediction that exhibit excessive dispersion/concentration?
3. Asymmetric **tail estimates**: Which strategy could be used to benefit from densities that assign too-low probability to the left tail compared to the right tail, or vice versa?

Since the strategy concern different payoff regions, I am initially looking at an option-based approach that employs calls and puts with different strikes.

Comment: Just a hint because I cannot disclose too much stuff: you can compare the risk-neutral density with the underlying density resulting from simulations (e.g. block bootstrap) where the drift has been changed to be risk-neutral. If you try to minimize some distance measure between the two distributions by changing a quantile-based filter applied to the bootstrapped returns, you get a tail-discount measure that can be traded with options.

Comment: "which strategy could be used to benefit from a density prediction that exhibit excessive dispersion/concentration": delta neutralized option straddle.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is too simple, but here’s what I think of when you ask for option strategies given a view on forecasted price densities:

-Think returns are going to be higher than expected? Buy a call.

-Think returns are going to be lower than expected? Buy a put

-Think scale is going to be higher than than expected? Long straddle or long strangle.

-Think scale is going to be lower than expected? Short straddle or short strangle.

-Think left tail weight too low/high? Buy/sell an OTM put

-Think right tail weight too low/high? Buy/sell an OTM call